# How to specify the field type that may be automatically set up when inserting data into Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have a question about Apache IoTDB. The value of a certain field in my database is 1, but when I queried this value, the value returned 1.0. Does that may because my fields are automatically created when inserting data? (Since I don't remember I setup any data type) And also how do I specify my data type of these fields in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the data type of Apache IoTDB is automatically determined based on the value of the written data. If you want to change, in this case, from `1.0` to `1` for your data type, you can use `integer_string_infer_type` to change the data type inferred from the integer string. The default setting of this parameter is FLOAT, so that's why you got `1.0`.